# Touch and click listeners android

Tags: android, android-layout

How to perform touch event and click event on a single view please give a proper suggestion

I would very thankful to you.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do anything in the touch event like i will show one example for the touch You can achieve the all things  like single press long press on fling etc....
If you have any doubt comment it...
Sample is....

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private CalendarView view ;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());
    view = (CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendar);

}
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {       
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
class GestureListener implements OnGestureListener
{

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Down List");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        System.out.println("Fly List");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Long press");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
            float distanceX, float distanceY) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

        System.out.println("Press List");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Single Tap List");
        return false;
    }

}
  }
```